# Deep pagination for filtered search results in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I need to implement a Node web service that reads up to 1,000,000 documents through MarkLogic REST API based on a filtered search query and convert the results into an archive.

Reading 1,000,000 documents at once, together with content transformation, results in a timeout. My thought is to use pagination. But does it make sense to paginate on filtered search results for bulk export?

My understanding is that filtered search doesn't support efficient deep paging as it always needs to start from the beginning every time.

I know filtered search query is not performant to start with, but that is a separate question.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You really should see if you can do this without filtering. If you're actually needing filtering, then pagination won't help you. You'll be best off doing it in one long-running query. In that case you can try increasing the timeouts. However, if you CAN get it working unfiltered then you have choices: you can paginate, use MLCP to make the archive, use CORB, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your insight and suggestions, @hunterhacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to run filtered, I'd make the search return uri only. You will probably still need to increase timeouts a lot, but you won't risk blowing caches, since holding content of 1 mln docs will be practically impossible. You could invoke custom code, which could look something like this:

```
cts:search(collection(), $myQuery, "filtered") ! xdmp:node-uri(.)
```

Once you have pulled the full list of uris across, you can then page through the uris, and fetch them in batches.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade!